# array set title and alt in the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

Using this code:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail("mini-me", array(
        'class' => 'x-img smpic x-img-circle',
        'alt' => the_title(),
        'title' => the_title()
    ));
}
?>
```

However, alt and title are being output as text on website instead of enclosed tags. What should the syntax be instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `get_the_title` instead of `the_title` - from the Function Reference:

- `the_title` - Display or retrieve the current post title with optional markup.
- `get_the_title` - Retrieve post title.

You might notice that `the_title` says "Display or retrieve" - and it's true, you can pass `false` to the third parameter of `the_title` to get it's output as a return value instead of it `echo`'ing directly to the page, i.e.

```
$mytitle = the_title( '', '', false );
```

**EDIT**: Updated your code to show this in action:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $title = get_the_title();
    the_post_thumbnail("mini-me", array(
        'class' => 'x-img smpic x-img-circle',
        'alt'   => $title,
        'title' => $title,
    ) );
}
?>
```